# Geometry question involving cuboid

Tags: geometry

For n by m rectangle, which is formed by nm number of 1 by 1 squares, if we draw a line conecting opposite vertices, it's not hard to see that the number of squares it crosses should be n + m - gcd(m, n), but I was just wondering how we could extend this result to multi-dimensional cases.

For instance, let's say we have n1 by n2 by n3 rectangular prism, which is formed by 
n1 * n2 * n3  number of 1 by 1 by 1 cubes, and we draw a line connecting opposite vertices. 
How many squares will it cross? and is there any way of coming up with some sort of 
general rule for n-dimensional case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean: “How many *cubes* will it cross?”, dont't you?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the special case where all your values are pairwise coprime. What would your answer be, and why?

**Hint:** It is easy to justify the answer using a bijection argument.

**Hint:** Now, what happens if the terms are not coprime? What breaks down in the bijection argument?